How to Handle Zero Stock Returns When Calculating Excess Return in CAPM Analysis?
everyone. I am new to this beautiful quantitative field, and I have a question regarding CAPM. I'm using daily frequency data of S&P500 from Jan 1990 to September 2024. When analysing my dataset, I noticed some days where the stock returns (e.g., for ADI) are exactly 0 after conversion. I'm unsure how to handle these 0 values when calculating the excess return.
Specifically, should I:

Remove the 0-value return days from the dataset?

Keep them and calculate the excess return as usual?


Here is the following dataset:


I would be glad if someone could give me any idea about data on financial datasets like the pre-processing of the S&P 500.

What is wrong with a return being zero?

@RichardHardy That is my concern; from 1990-01-05 to 1990-01-11, there was a return of 0 for six consecutive days. I was questioning whether it's a mistake or if it happens in the market a lot, so I should take it into consideration when I estimate Ordinary Least Square  Regression. Thanks a lot for the comment

If this is erroneous data, you may want to exclude it or replace with more typical values (data imputation). But if it is actual data, excluding it would distort the picture. Your findings would only apply to days when the returns are nonzero. Since it is hard to predict which day will have zero return in the future, these findings would be less useful than ones that use all data and thus apply to all days.
But perhaps these zero returns do not make a significant difference in your results? If you get about the same results when including vs. excluding them, you need not worry much about which option you choose.

This apporach make sense, this is a real data. I think you made a clear point. I've a bit low R2  value ( 0.32) thats is why I was wondering if there is any problem in the data.
